# How to load a whole directory using Class-Path: jar manifest header?

Tags: java, regex, jar, relative-path, manifest.mf

If in the manifest for a jar file that needs to load **non executable jars**, I have the `Class-Path:` specification and then **a directory holding the jars as the class path instead of a jar file**. Will the manifest then load the whole directory or will it just fail?

Update:
I tried to use `Class-Path: foo/*` however it failed to load the foo directory. Does the manifest classpath not support regex>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your `foo` directory contains only `.class` files, you can safely set the `Class-Path:` header like this:

```
Class-Path: foo/
```

Since you have non executable jars in it, you should use a build tool like Maven to generate the `Class-Path:` entry for you. The non executable jars will be dependencies of your Maven project.

Reference:

- [JAR : MANIFEST.MF Class-Path referencing a directory](http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.in/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html)

Comment: Thanks! was actually using ant. But still a great deal of help!